# Marking view as dirty from another class

Tags: android

Right now I'm building a game for Android. I have a class game.java that calls board.xml as it's view. Board.xml has the following:

```
... //Score info
<edu.xxx.yyy.zzz.BoardView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"/>
... //pause button
... //submit button
```

BoardView is a Java class that extends View and is used to draw the game board. Everything is being displayed correctly. I want to know if I can implement code in game.java that can mark areas of BoardView as dirty (namely after I hit that Submit button which changes some global variables).

Answer (score 2):

Give the BoardView an id in xml with the attribute

```
 android:id="@+id/myBoardView"
```

Then just grab the BoardView using findViewById

```
 BoardView myBV = (BoardView) findViewById(R.id.myBoardView);
```

Then simply mark the areas dirty that you want to be made dirty by using the invalidate method

```
 myBV.invalidate(); //invalidates the entire BoardView
```

or

```
 Rect dirty = new Rect(...);
 myBV.invalidate(dirty); //marks the area defined by dirty as dirty
```

or

```
 int left = 0; int right = 10; int top = 0; int bot = 10;
 myBV.invalidate(left, top, right, bot); //invalidates the area defined by these coords as dirty
```